# ¿Cómo crear un TimePickerDialog desde BottomSheet?

Tags: android, datetimepicker

Actualmente estoy trabajando con DatepickerDialog y TimePickerDialog, he podido construir un DatePicker sin embargo, cuando intento construir el TimePicker de la misma forma no me es posible. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo de la forma en que quiero implementarlo?

Este es mi código:

```
private void timePicker(){

    int hour = 0;
    int minute = 0;
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
    timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePickerDialog view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), Integer.toString(hourOfDay), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, hour, minute, false);
}


public void showDatePickerDialog() {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            String date = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) +"-"+String.valueOf(monthOfYear)
                    +"-"+String.valueOf(year);
            textViewDate.setText(date);
        }
    }, yy, mm, dd);
    datePicker.show();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podrán ver, el showDatePickerDialog() funciona de manera correcta, en donde tengo error es en el TimePicker.

Gracias!

Comment: crea una variable Context fuera del timePicker y instanciala asi context = this; luego en ves de getContext utiliza context prueba eso creo q ese es el error

Comment: Más bien creo que el error está en el constructor por qué incluso comento el toast y no funciona , me sigue apareciendo en rojo... 

Comment: cuando compilas te sale el error copialo para verlo mejor

Comment: O: ! me sale esto.

error: constructor TimePickerDialog in class TimePickerDialog cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: FragmentActivity,<anonymous OnTimeSetListener>,int,int,boolean
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78887/discussion-between-alex-rivas-and-alex-trujillo).

Comment: revisa el chat que te respondi alli

Comment: como te dije en el chat a mi el error que me da es del context no el constructor.

Comment: una pregunta el bottomsheet es un fragment?? disculpa la pregunta es que aun estoy empezando

Comment: si. Mira mi  objeto de Bottomsheet extiende de :  BottomSheetDialogFragment

Comment: checa:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment

Comment: No es un fragmento del todo pero si . Puedes checar el link de Android Documentación  que mande a Alex Rivas , ahí aparece el árbol.

Comment: Encontré esta respuesta que me ayudó a poder hacer el TimePicker desde el BotomSheet. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50613108/5319007

Comment: todo era cuestion de buscar mas me alegra que hayas resuelto el problema si te puedo ayudar en algo mas simplemente pregunta lo poco que se lo comparto..